# Plotting region with negative Gaussian curvature?

Tags: plotting

I am plotting a surface using ParametricPlot3D. Is there a way that only the region with negative Gaussian curvature is plotted?

Comment: Try `RegionFunction`!  It would be very helpful if you provide a minimal example.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you for your reply. supposing that I am plotting a cyclide `ParametricPlot3D[
 ResourceFunction["Cyclide"][.3, 
  1.5, {u, v}], {u, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {v, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}]` and I only wanted to plot the regions with negative Gaussian curvature. I wasn't sure how to use RegionFunction. thank you for your reply!

Comment: If you know the curvature `curv[u,v]` try `ParametricPlot3D[…,RegionFunction->Function[{u,v},curv[u,v]<0]]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a `ResourceFunction` that can compute Gaussian curvature which allows you to incorporate the comment by Ulrich Neumann

```
Clear[surf, curv]
surf[u_, v_] = ResourceFunction["Cyclide"][.3, 1.5, {u, v}];
curv[u_, v_] = 
  ResourceFunction["GaussianCurvature"][#, {u, v}] &@surf[u, v];
ParametricPlot3D[
 surf[u, v], {u, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {v, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{u, v}, curv[u, v] < 0]]
```

[image: Regions of negative curvature of a cyclide]